# How can calculated variance between months with MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, variance, measure

I want calculated variance of PeriodsToDate between months with MDX.

For calculate Sum Amount i use thsi query : SUM(PERIODSTODATE( [DATE].[MONTH].[All],[DATE].[MONTH].CurrentMember),
[Measures].[AMOUNT])

I want the result of column "%Varicance_Amount_Month"

[image]

Thank you !

Comment: before asking a new question, it's always nice to mark your earlier questions that were answered as answered.

Comment: can you please share the query you have worked so far and a screen shot of how the result data should look.

Comment: ok it's done thank's !

Comment: Can you share your complete query. I would like to help but I need to understand what are you doing in your query.